# unlink() triggers open_basedir restriction. But every other function works

Tags: php, unlink

I have the following constant: `FSROOT` that is set as follows: `getcwd()`. I can use this constant everywhere in my app and don't have to worry about paths, for example: `require_once(FSROOT . '/includes/php/something.php)`.

However, I have recently implemented some files in my app, and on certain events I need to delete some files, here's what I do locally:

```
unlink( FSROOT . '/somefile.pdf' );
```

And this works perfectly, in my local environment. On the server however I get an error:

```
unlink(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/mnt/var/[...]/app/somefile.pdf) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/[...]/app/)
```

So the problem seems to be the `/mnt/` directory that is returned from `getcwd()` but that doesn't match my allowed paths!

I am a bit confused because the `FSROOT` path can be used in any function but `unlink()`. This is also why I don't want to change it. Is there another way to delete the file? Or will I have to manually create another constant to be used with `unlink()`?

Or is there an alternative to getcwd() that I should use?

Comment: if you are trying to delete any file that is outside of open_basedir configuration this error will be triggered. You can check this config in php.ini.

Comment: If you're using PHP >= 5.3 you could also turn SafeMode off, which is deprecated in 5.3, then there'll be no more issues with `open_basedir`...

Comment: PLB: Thanks, so I am looking for ways around this! 
Havelock: I can't do this as I am on a shared host. :(

Comment: Turns out I was storing the file's path in a non-persistent way, and my host sometimes moves my app around on the server, so the path would change, and the unlink() would try to access a non-existing path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was storing the file's path in a non-persistent way, and my host sometimes moves my app around on the server, so the path would change, and the unlink() would try to access a non-existing path... So there really isn't anything to be answered here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using dirname in combination with **FILE** to get the correct path?

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returns the same path as `getcwd()`